# How to make spaghetti stick together?

Tags: boiling, spaghetti

I am a person that likes spaghetti that is stuck together, al dente, so it's nice and chewy.

I haven't been able to find any advice on how to cook spaghetti so that it sticks together, but rather the contrary, as it seems most people would prefer spaghetti that is separated.

So, logically, I did exactly the opposite of what these sources recommended so that it would stick together (not stirring, not letting it boil so much that it separates itself), which seems to work well, but not as much as I would like it to. Some of it sticks together, but not all of it.

Is there a way I could make spaghetti such that all of it would stick together ALL the time? Like just one big clump?

Comment: Have you tried boiling it more than the required time? That makes it sticky, but also mushy and extra soft

Answer (score 5):

Easy....cook per the package instruction, with no oil in water.  Drain well through a strainer.  Allow to sit in the strainer or in a bowl long enough to allow the moisture to flash off.  Your pasta will be sticky and clumpy.  To further enhance the effect, refrigerate.  Saucing or oil will separate the strands,  If you like to eat it that way, there are recipes for using leftover spaghetti, and cooking it with egg, that results in a sort of pasta fritatta. You might enjoy that as well.

Comment: But I was hoping more for something that was a bit more fresh: I particularly wouldn't want to let it sit for 15 mins and definitely wouldn't want to put it in the fridge: I'd want to just drain it and eat it.

Comment: @NotAPro, you don't need to leave it 15 for it to stick, just long enough so that the water evaporates off it. The type of pasta you use will also help, make sure it's a fairly cheap brand

Comment: Agree with @Bee.  I edited my response.  It might not take 15 min.

Answer (score 0):

1) **Heavily salt your pasta water.** Kosher salt is recommended, because it does not contain anti-clumping agents that you do not need in pasta water. The salt will season your pasta, and is a requirement for good tasting pasta.

2) **Do not oil your pasta water.** Adding oil to your pasta water is largely superficial, and does not really help prevent a boil-over. When you go to strain your pasta, it does cause the pasta to be poured through oily water, however, which will leave a thin layer of oil on the pasta, and prevent both the pasta from sticking together - *and* - the sauce from sticking to the pasta. Just don't do this.

3) **Do not rinse your pasta.** Rinsing your pasta after straining removes all the leftover starches on the surface of the pasta. The leftover starches are necessary to both let pasta stick together, as well as for the sauce to stick to the pasta. If you rinse your pasta, your sauce will not adhere to the pasta - which is bad. For your purposes, not rinsing the pasta will also help it clump together better.